# How to set aac file bitrate?

Tags: android, arrays, audio, kotlin, aac

I am trying to generate aac file on Android. I successfully done it. But I have a little unpleasant thing. When I open my file in VLC it detect my file with following parameters:

- sampleSize = 32 (but it is recorded with 16 bit frame size)
- sampleRate = 16 (but it is recorded with 8 kHz)
- channelsCount = 2 (but it is recorded with 1 channel)

Where I should specify sample size? I can specify only sample rate.

Here my code which generates ADTS header

```
val id = 0
val layer = 0
val protectionAbsent = 1
val profile = 2
val frequencyIndex = 11
val privateBit = 0
val channelConfig = 1
val originalCopy = 0
val home = 0
val copyritingIdBit = 0
val copyritingIdStart = 0
val frameLength = 775

val arr = ByteArray(7)
arr[0] = 0xff.toByte()
arr[1] = (0xf0 or ((id shl 3) and 0b1000) or ((layer shl 1) and 0b110) or (protectionAbsent and 0b1)).toByte()
arr[2] = ((((profile - 1) shl 6) and 0b11000000) or ((frequencyIndex shl 2) and 0b111100) or ((privateBit shl 1) and 0b00000010) or ((channelConfig shr 2) and 0b1)).toByte()
arr[3] = (((channelConfig shl 6) and 0b11000000) or ((originalCopy shl 5) and 0x100000) or ((home shl 4) and 0b10000) or ((copyritingIdBit shl 3) and 0b00001000) or ((copyritingIdStart shl 2) and 0b00000100) or ((frameLength shr 11) and 0b11)).toByte()
arr[4] = ((frameLength shr 3) and 0xff).toByte() 
arr[5] = (((frameLength shl 5) and 0b11100000) or 0x1f).toByte()
arr[6] = 0xfc.toByte()
```

When I change frequency to 16kHz, it is detected as 32 kHz. MacOs detects frequency correctly.

All players play record correctly.

Comment: This doesn't look like Android Java code... Variables are not declared like this and there is no such `toByte()` method.

Comment: This is Kotlin!

Comment: Can you tell us the first 7 bytes (ADTS) of your output `.aac` file? Use a hex editor to check the file bytes.

Comment: fff9 6040 60ff fc

Comment: or fff1 6040 60ff fc, no difference